# Trying to automate with Selenium in parallel, but multiple webdriver instances freak out

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver, phantomjs

So I'm trying to create a java program that uses Selenium to automate a WebDriver to perform tasks on a website. At the moment, I'm using it for work in order to automate an annoying task where the user has to upload files to our database. I've already successfully made a program which automates this, and saved myself hours of manual work.

Now I'm trying to get the program to run multiple browsers in ***parallel***. I want to do this in order to speed up the rate at which I can upload files because most of the time is lost waiting for pages to load.

I've tested this with a much simpler version of my program and have managed to speed up simple tasks by 2-10 times by having tens to hundreds of threads open with their own WebDrivers.

The problem is, whenever I run more than ***1*** WebDriver the entire thing begins to randomly freak out at times, and at other times not work at all. I tried to use *'PhantomJSDriver'* along with the latest *'PhantomJS.exe'*, however at times it would work, and most of the times it would do nothing. The same program that runs flawlessly with one driver running breaks down when they are ran in parallel.

I've been trying to find reasons as to why this happens and ways around it, but I haven't found anything definite that I can use.

**How can I go about automating web browsing in parallel with Selenium if possible, and if not, where should I look to in order to do this?**

Comment: have you figured that out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running multiple Selenium tests at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005672/running-multiple-selenium-tests-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need, it is called "Selenium Grid"

http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: I'll look into it, but will this allow me to run multiple drivers on a single machine? My goal is to automate in parallel from a program on a single machine. I'm not looking to automate on multiple machines (machine referring to actual computers)

Answer (score 2):

Actually using `Grid` you can automate the tests in parallel using a same machine or by using multiple machines (here machines in the sense of individual computers).

I hope this [link will show you how to run a tests in parallel in same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916029/selenium-grid2-howto-run-5-browsers-in-paralel).

In the above given link the user said to create a five different programs to run in parallel. If you want to run single program in parallel, then just use `TestNg or Junit` to trigger multiple instance.

This is the sample `TestNg config code` to run a test in parallel. Here i ran two threads. So it will invoke the TestNg `@Test` method of a given class file `com.test.workflow.device.testcase20` in two threads.

```
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
 <suite name="Suite1"  parallel="test" thread-count="2">
   <test name="Testcase20" >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.workflow.device.testcase20"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
 </suite>
```

By using above xml file you can acheive parallelism in webdriver using grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Sahi http://sahi.co.in/. It can run multiple instances of browsers in parallel.

Do look at how Sahi does file uploads though. http://sahi.co.in/w/_setFile

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run selenium instances concurrently. When selenium runs browser instances, it opens the connection on port [7055](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriverInternals) by default.

So, if you want to run multiple instances, you have to run them on different ports.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you build a driver for each browser and let your code know that you use more than multiple drivers. Other suggestion as already described above, using Selenium Grid is the best solution available:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5431/how-to-open-multiple-browsers-using-webdriver
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Answer (score 0):

if you use webdriver , try maven-surefire-plugin :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkCount>4</forkCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

in code use option 'forkCount' value 4 - number of processors. 4 processors = 4 JVM. U can start webdriver for each JVM !
link info http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html